# searching and processing particular directory and files in python

Tags: python, file

In my present directory I have the following files:
project1, project5, junk, temp and personal

I  would like to walk through the sub directories at this level only.
For directories other than junk, temp and personal I would like to open and process a particular file present in them say called project.c

```
for dirs in os.walk('.').next()[1] :  
      if dirs !='junk' or dirs!='temp' or dirs != 'personal':  
        print dirs  
        print "relevant\n"
        # file = open(project//project.c) # process relevant files
```

How do I go about doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
import os
import glob

ignoreDirs = ['junk', 'temp', 'personal']

for x in glob.glob('*'):
    if (os.path.isdir(x) == False):
        continue

    if (x in ignoreDirs):
        continue

    # ... do processing work here ...
```

Answer (score 0):

And here's another, somewhat similar way

```
ignored=set(('junk','temp','personal'))
projectfiles=set(('project.c','Makefile.in'))

for direntry in os.listdir('.') :
   if not direntry in ignored :
      filename=os.path.join(os.path.dirname('.'),direntry)
      if os.path.isdir(filename) :
         for projectfile in projectfiles :
            projectfilepath=os.path.join(filename,projectfile)
            if os.path.exists(projectfilepath) :
            fd=open(projectfilepath)
            # Do whatever processing is needed
            fd.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk), dirnames can be modified to affect the traversal:

> When topdown is True, the caller can
>   modify the dirnames list in-place
>   (perhaps using del or slice
>   assignment), and walk() will only
>   recurse into the subdirectories whose
>   names remain in dirnames; this can be
>   used to prune the search, impose a
>   specific order of visiting, or even to
>   inform walk() about directories the
>   caller creates or renames before it
>   resumes walk() again. Modifying
>   dirnames when topdown is False is
>   ineffective, because in bottom-up mode
>   the directories in dirnames are
>   generated before dirpath itself is
>   generated.

So, you can do something like:

```
def clean(dirs):
    to_ignore = ("tmp", "junk", "personal")
    for d in to_ignore:
        if d in dirs:
            dirs.remove(d)

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    clean(dirnames)
    # process relevant files
```